# How do I find which cluster my data belongs to using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

I just ran PCA and then K-means Clustering algorithm on my data, after running the algorithm I get 3 clusters. I am trying to figure out which clusters my input belongs to , in order to gather some qualitative attributes about the input. My input is customer ID and the variables I used for clustering were the spend patterns on certain products

Below is the code I ran for K means, looking for some inputs on how to map this back to the source data to see which cluster the input belongs to :

```
kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters=3)
X_clustered=kmeans.fit_predict(x_10d)

LABEL_COLOR_MAP = {0:'r', 1 : 'g' ,2 : 'b'}
label_color=[LABEL_COLOR_MAP[l] for l in X_clustered]

#plot the scatter diagram

plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.scatter(x_10d[:,0],x_10d[:,2] , c=label_color, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: `x_10d[i]` belongs to cluster `X_clustered[i]`, if that is what you are asking

Comment: If df is my dataframe that has all the input customer ID's as well as purchase data, then how do I map all the customer ID's to their respective clusters in python?

Comment: What is "map" exactly? It seems to me that `df['id'][i]` maps to `X_clustered[i]` already (assuming column named so).

Comment: By map, I mean, now that I know my data has 3 clusters, I want to be able to break out the ID's into each of these clusters , to see if Customer A belongs to Cluster 1 , Customer B to Cluster 2 and so on. Also want to know the size of each of the clusters. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add the cluster labels back in your dataframe, and assuming x_10d is your dataframe, you can do:

x_10d["cluster"] = X_clustered

This will add a new column in your dataframe called "cluster" which should contain the cluster label for each of your rows.

Comment: In my dataset,
x_10d=pca.fit_transform(X_std) - result of PCA 
My source dataset is a SQL query that I have stored in a dataframe df
df = bb.query_presto(
    namespace='finance',
    sql=sql
    
)

Comment: Ok, great! If you get  a chance, if you could mark the question as answered that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To group instances by their assigned cluster id

```
N_CLUSTERS = 3
clusters = [x_10d[X_clustered == i] for i in range(N_CLUSTERS)]
# replace x_10d with where you want to retrieve data

# to have a look
for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
    print('Cluster {} has {} members: {}...'.format(i, len(c), c[0]))

# which prints
# Cluster 0 has 37 members: [0.95690664 0.07578273 0.0094432 ]...
# Cluster 1 has 30 members: [0.03124354 0.97932615 0.47270528]...
# Cluster 2 has 33 members: [0.26331688 0.5039502  0.72568873]...
```