# Python: Determine which cluster the data points belong to

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Apologies if this is a duplicate somewhat, but I have tried the solution presented in [How do I find which cluster my data belongs to using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146570/how-do-i-find-which-cluster-my-data-belongs-to-using-python), but it didn't work for me.

I have a data frame, `indicators_df`, in which the first column is the index and the other three are floats:

```
# Sample data    
indicators_df.head(4)

index     1      2       3
  a    52.645  36.167  18.762
  b    34.536  26.772  28.438
  c    46.376  21.784  36.884
  d    33.687  24.979  27.349
```

I had to scale it before I put it through a K-Means Clustering process to get the below plot:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, RobustScaler

indicators_df

# Define each scaler
robust_scaler = RobustScaler()

# Scale data
X_train_robust = robust_scaler.fit_transform(indicators_df)

# Create an instance of kmeans model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 0).fit(X_train_robust)

# Define cluster centers
cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
C1 = cluster_centers[:, 0]
C2 = cluster_centers[:, 1]
C3 = cluster_centers[:, 2]

# Define figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# Define x, y, and z axis
x = X_train_robust[:,0]
y = X_train_robust[:,1]
z = X_train_robust[:,2]

# Define axis labels
column_names = indicators_df.columns
ax.set_xlabel(column_names[0])
ax.set_ylabel(column_names[1])
ax.set_zlabel(column_names[2])

# Define markers and colors
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = kmeans.labels_.astype(float), cmap = 'winter', marker = 'o')
ax.scatter(C1, C2, C3, marker = 'x', color = 'red')

# Define title
plt.title("Visualization of clustered data with {} clusters".format(cluster), fontweight = 'bold')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to link it back to `indicators_df` so that there's a new column called "ClusterID" so that indicators_df would look something like this:

```
index     1      2       3      ClusterID
  a    52.645  36.167  18.762      1
  b    34.536  26.772  28.438      2
  c    46.376  21.784  36.884      3
  d    33.687  24.979  27.349      2
```

I tried `X_train_robust["cluster"] = kmeans`, but that didn't work.

What do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you're looking for " kmeans.labels_ " . It returns array of labels(cluster id's) for each point.

Answer (score 0):

The labels are stored in the field `kmeans.labels_`.

Don't use the entire object `kmeans` instead. Such details matter in programming. The example you linked used `fit_predict` instead of `fit` - which is similar, but returns `labels_`.